# How do I diagnose/debug a 500 internal server error for nodejs/expressjs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, windows, http

So to post data from HTML form to express js server I keep getting and Internal Server Error 500. It doesn't say why, just prints POST /routeitisreaching 500

How do I go about figuring out what is causing the issue? It is not even hitting that route because I have a console.log in place as the route code executes and that doesn't get run.

This is from the issue I posted [Internal Error 500 at POST request Express JS and Formidable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55537877/internal-error-500-at-post-request-express-js-and-formidable?noredirect=1#comment97779766_55537877)

Is there a log file getting saved somewhere in windows where I can see the details of what is happening from form submission to backend? I am really stuck need help.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? My app has started doing that and I'm completely lost as to why!

Comment: Inbox me the screenshots of your code I will assist you. It has been some time I have forgotten what was I do on this post. @Georges

Comment: Many thanks for you reply and offer to assist, @mysamza. I actually think I solved the problem; I just don't quite understand how. I moved that particular route up in the list and it started working. I knew the last route in the list would be sort of a 'catch all' but do they have to be in alphabetical order or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be helpful https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html

You can also try commenting slices of code and check if server responds.

Comment: The problem is I can't slice the code because the POST request doesn't even reach the route. I have a console.log right at the beginning. router.post('/upload', function(req, res){console.log("we entered this route")}); Anyway, I will look into the link you posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I encountered same issue and the Terminal does not giving any error message.So here is what we can do

At the end of your app.js(main file) write following code

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  console.error(err);
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: err
  });
});
```

and then create a new file error.ejs under views folder. In /views/error.ejs write

```
There was some error
<pre>
<%= message; %>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<%= error; %>
```

And you should now see more details about your error. I helped me debugging 500 errors a lot. Hopefully this help other too

Comment: I tried this, but couldn't get it to do anything / didn't get anywhere with it...

Comment: @BeninCA in case of 500 error occurrence, this page is expected to display error. is it not showing up anything to you?

Comment: Right; but perhaps my configuration is just different.

Comment: `message: err.message,` help me