# Insert data to oracle db having date datatype and autoincrement value

Tags: node.js, oracle

I am working on an api in node.js to insert data. I have a table in oracle with below structure

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
id id_seq.nextval,
start_date DATE,
primary key(id) 
);
```

Now I am trying to insert into db like this

```
const connection = oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig)
let options = {
  autoCommit: true,
  bindDefs:[
  {type: oracledb.NUMBER},  {type: oracledb.DATE}
 ]
}
let binds = [
[1,moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')],
[2,moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')]
]
const result = connection.executeMany('insert into my_table values(:1, :2, :3)', options, binds);
```

But this solution is not working. Can someone confirm where I am making mistake. Also, How can I add dynamic autoincrement id instead of hardcoded value.

Comment: Your table has 2 columns, one number and one a date. Why are you using 3 bind values in the query and why are you passing 2 dates in the JavaScript code? Also, your `CREATE TABLE` statement is invalid as the `ID` column does not define a data-type [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ku7-oF7s). Your question is filled with inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple.
You have 2 columns

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
id id_seq.nextval,
start_date DATE,
primary key(id) 
);
```

When you try to insert data, Oracle think, that you already have your own value for all columns, including id.
Just do not put any values into id column, like this:

```
insert into my_table (start_date) values (:1)
```

You can play with it here: https://dbfiddle.uk/7jZpj-r4

btw, here you can find another techniques: [How to create id with AUTO_INCREMENT on Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle)

Comment: I know the query from oracle, but I need to implement same in node.js. The above node.js code I have shared is not working.

Comment: Do you have any error messages about your case?

Comment: I have a table with around 100 columns, and it's difficult to write all the field names in insert statement, so I have used column index like in above code. I am facing issue because because of date type. Also I have passed hard-coded index as auto increment key.

Comment: I can see only 500 response from api

Comment: Ok, if you cannot cut field list, you can use trigger to fill this values from sequence, as proposed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle

Comment: About issue with datatype - you have 2 columns, one in number format, another in date... but on the row with `let binds` you put two values and both in the date format... maybe first-one should be number, for example 0

Comment: About debug 500 http error, I do not have a lot of expirience with it, but I beleave, you can add some additional information, maybe this post can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550228/how-do-i-diagnose-debug-a-500-internal-server-error-for-nodejs-expressjs

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id         NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  start_date DATE,
  primary key(id) 
);
```

Then your `INSERT` statement should be either:

```sql
INSERT INTO my_table (start_date) VALUES (:1)
```

or:

```sql
INSERT INTO my_table (id, start_date) VALUES (DEFAULT, :1)
```

---

> I have a table with around 100 columns, and it's difficult to write all the field names in insert statement

Just write them out once, it is not too hard and probably takes less time than you spent asking this question.

If you really cannot, then copy-paste the DDL statement for the table and delete bits until you have only the column names.

Alternatively, query the data dictionary and copy-paste from that:

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(column_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_id)
FROM   user_tab_columns
WHERE  table_name = 'MY_TABLE';
```

There are many ways of solving the problem of writing out the names of columns and you should only need to solve that small issue once.

---

Then in Node, when you want to bind values. If you have two columns and one of them is auto-generated then you only need **ONE** bind value.